# TFS Build 2012 Definition file paths

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

If I include a script in version control in my build definition arguments ($/mypath/myfile.ps1) does the build process automatically get the latest version of that file OR do I have to explicitly pull that file down myself in Source Settings?

It looks like sometimes I have to do manually and sometimes the build knows the file is in Version control and pulls down for me.

I am confused as to when I have to pull files down explicitly and when I don't have to. :|

Comment: Where are you using that file path? If you want the a version pulling down, you can use the Source Mappings.

Answer (score 0):

On the Source Settings tab, you have to specify the version-control folders that contain the files that your build process requires in the Working folders table, which means you need to specify the folder include myfile.ps1 file on the Source Settings tab.

Then when you queue build, if you don't specify the version on Process tab, TFS will get the latest version of the folders specified on Source Settings tab:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from XAML Build and it seems that the question concerns Build vNext. Anyhow I think that the message you want to send is that only files/directories specified in Repository Mappings (Build vNext) / Source Settings (XAML Build) will be pulled down to the build agent.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard, the title indicates TFS Build 2012 Definition, so I assume it's XAML build. We need OP to clarify it. :-)